# From Cloud Build to Cloud Memorystore in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an instance in Google Cloud Memorystore.  I want to connect to it from builds that I run in Google Cloud Build.

I created the following configuration file for Cloud Build:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - run
      - redis
      - redis-cli
      - -h
      - 10.1.2.3
      - PUBLISH
      - cloud-build-1
      - msg1
```

(I've changed the IP address, but that's an unimportant detail.)

I ran that configuration file using the following command:

```
gcloud builds submit --no-source --config cloudbuild.yaml
```

The build failed.  The output of the command included:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 10.1.2.3:6379: Connection timed out
```

(Again, I have changed the IP address.)

How can I get this `redis-cli` command to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you are trying to perform is not currently possible. You see, in order to connect to your Memorystore instance a VM or Kubernetes Cluster has to be in the same GCP project, region and VPC network. When you use Cloud Build you are using a VM in which you can't select the region nor network.

Doing some research about this, I could find that Google Engineering team has been working on what is currently known as Worker pools. This product [1]  is currently in alfa state and it's not recommended for implementation on production environments as it could change without notice.

Using the cloud shell you could create a machine on certain network to gain access to your resources such as memorystore. You could also specify the region, disk size or machine type of your cloud build worker.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/worker-pools/create